# .NET standardOut is not getting redirected

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a part of a code where I need to start up a console application from my .NET console application and get its output and in the best scenario also print that output. But I am getting error:

> StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet

I got `RedirectStandardOutput` set to *true* and the thread has according to log started (I got "read started" printed out).

I am attaching problematic pieces of the code below. Anyone got an idea where the problem is? I will be grateful for any useful advice.

```
Thread readingThread = new Thread(Read);

ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        FileName = "../../" + path + "/server_run.sh",
                    };

info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.FileName = "../../" + path + "/server_run.sh";

using (Process server = Process.Start(info))
{
    readingThread.Start(server);
    Console.WriteLine("Starting the server");
    int serverNumber = serverPaths.FindIndex(x => x == path); 
    Console.WriteLine(serverNumber);
    serverNumbers.Insert(serverNumber, server.Id);
    int i = 0;

    foreach (int a in serverNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("index: " + i + " " + a);
        i++;
    }

    //////////////string ProcessID;
    Console.WriteLine(server.Id.ToString()); ////////////////

    Console.WriteLine("Server started");
}

readingThread.Join();

private static void Read(object parameter)
{
    Console.WriteLine("read started");

    Process process = parameter as Process;
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MyProcOutputHandler);
}

private static void MyProcOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    // Collect the sort command output. 
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the error text is pretty clear

Comment: You exit the using block and the Process instance is disposed of. Need to Thread.Join without leaving the using block, or not wrap your process in a using block at all

Comment: Thank you for explaining @Oguz Ozgul. I will try your solution tomorrow and I will inform you how it went. I am new to threading and made this from multiple tutorials, so I probably mixed wrong parts :D

Comment: I followed your advice, now the code executes without an error, but I am not reciving any output from the program I am running in the process... like the process.OutputDataReceived funtions never fires. Tried multiple workarounds but nothing seems to work... Any advice?